# how to convert input stream to byte array to string in android

Tags: android, arduino, serial-port, inputstream, bytearrayoutputstream

I'm working on RFID serial port. In this I have a source code in that mentioned like this `new SerialPort(new File("/dev/ttyS3"), 19200);` its working perfect I am getting an output, but not in good encoding I tried all encodings, but it's not working.

I am getting an output from `InputStream`:

```java
mInputStream = mSerialPort.getInputStream();

private byte[] reciveBuffer=new byte[128];;
private int size = 0;

size = mInputStream.read(reciveBuffer);
 //i checked all encodings
String message = new String(reciveBuffer,0, size,Charset.forName("iso-8859-1"));
String message2 = new String(reciveBuffer,0, size,Charset.forName("windows-1252"));

assert message2.charAt(1) == '\u00E4';
String message3 = new String(reciveBuffer,0, size,Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
String encode=((reciveBuffer[0] & 128) == 0) ? "UTF-8" : "windows-1252";
String display = new String(reciveBuffer, 0, size);
```

But in string I'm getting:

```
3������`������`��xf���f���
```

from all encodings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following function:

```
private String Buff2String(byte[] buff) {
    String retVal = "";

    for(byte c : buff) {
        int i = c & 0xFF;
        retVal += (char)i;
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using extended ascii (>127) ?

Comment: i don't know i'm using normal encoding but there is a .so library serial port